# Tree Package, using newdata for prune.tree

Tags: r, tree

I divide a data frame to two `subsets`, `trainSet`, and `testSet`.  Then I use the tree command in the tree library:

```
tree1<-tree(y~., data=trainSet)
```

Then suppose I want to prune tree 1 using the testSet:

```
tree2<-prune.tree(tree1, newdata=testSet,best=7)
```

However, I noticed the calculation of tree2 is based on the original `trainSet`, not the newdata set (`testSet`).

I am not sure how to make the prune.tree command to work on the new dataset to choose the best tree.

Answer (score 0):

Using `model.frame`, this should work

```
tree2<-prune.tree(tree1, newdata=model.frame(testSet),best=7)
```

But I think it is better to use `cv.tree` which is will do the cross validation over your training data to, and call `prune.tree` over it.

```
cv.tree(tree1, , prune.tree)
```

here an example, suing **fgl** data from MASS package.

```
 data(fgl, package="MASS")
 fgl.tr <- tree(type ~ ., fgl)
 prune.tree(fgl.tr,newdata=model.frame(fgl[1:200,]))
```